# Install lpSolve package

Tags: r

I am new to R. Can anyone tell me how can I add the lpSolve package to R on a mac for example which folder to add it to, etc?

I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your new to R I'd suggest RStudio, a visual IDE for R. We use it for teaching students basic statistics and programming in R,

[RStudio Download](http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/)

Inside Rstudio

Menu Tools -> Install Packages

- Type Package Name
- Click Install

Now, after it installs, goto the Package Tab in the slower right pane.

Check the box next to the package and it will be loaded.

I'd suggest using the "lpSolveAPI" interface to lpSolve.

Answer (score 6):

You install R packages using `install.packages`; so try `install.packages('lpSolve', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com')` and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: ok, I did that. It says "The downloaded binary packages are in /var/folders/48/jxrps3zj12x8bn8rlpcv2dk80000gn/T//RtmpEfV38g/downloaded_packages"

Now, when I try to run this:
    > f.obj <- c(1,9,3)
    > f.con <- matrix (c(1,2,3,3,2,2),nrow = 2,byrow=TRUE)
    > f.dir <- c("<=","<=")
    > f.rhs <- c(9,15)
    > lp("max",f.obj,f.con,f.dir,f.rhs)
    Error: could not find function "lp"\

Comment: That means you've not `require(lpSolve)`... try that?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Just one last question, shouldn't it be lpSolve instead of ipSolve?

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me how can I do this in R.
Say I have to minimize a + b and the constraints are 
a >= 0, b >= 0, a + b + s1 = 5. I am not looking for the value of the objective function, I am just looking the for the syntax in R.

Comment: Post a separate question.